# Magento 2.4.2 - Why amazon scripts are flagged as CSP violation?

Tags: magento2, csp

I believe the Amazon integration is out of the box when it comes to Magento 2. Why is it being flagged in the chrome console as a CSP violation?

[image]

The module in vendor has its own csp_whitelist.xml file (/http/vendor/amzn/amazon-pay-module/etc/csp_whitelist.xml). How can I resolve it?

Comment: can you post the csp file you mention, the rules needs to used the right node: script-src in this case

Comment: Sorted it... Once added the connect-src and new error appeared for script-src and I didn't realize until I read your comment...